# SUPEE Patch 11219 not available for 1.7.0.2 Magento1

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, patches, supee-11219

After so many days,

Magento released patches for less than 1.9, But I could not see the patch for version 1.7.0.2

Does anyone any information when it will be available or will it be available?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the patch for 1.7.0.2 is now available on https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Answer (score 0):

May this patch will not come for 1.7.0.2, This only supports the Magento Versions:

```
Magento Commerce 1.9.0.0-1.14.4.1: SUPEE-11219 or upgrade to Magento Commerce 1.14.4.3.

Magento Open Source 1.5.0.0-1.9.4.1: SUPEE-11219 or upgrade to Magento Open Source 1.9.4.3.
```

For More Details Check this Link : [Click Here](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-11219)

Hope this will help You!!

Comment: it says 1.5.0.0-1.9.4.1 which means 1.7.0.2 is in that range and I can see 1.7.0.0 and 1.7.0.1 patches are available only this specific version is not available

Comment: Yes Exactly....